# How to get Gridview child view by using touch coordinates (x,y) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to get the child view of the Gridview by knowing the touch position (x,y) coordinates.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        for(int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                //check if finger position is above any child
                ImageView gridChild = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
                if(checkIntersection((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY(), gridChild.getLeft(), gridChild.getRight(), gridChild.getTop(), gridChild.getBottom())) 
                {
                   gridChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_square);
                   break;
                }
        }
break;
```

I have the above code but this happens many times per second and I believe it is too intense. I thought that if I could get the child View object that the user is touching just by using the touch x,y coordinates I won't need to loop through all the childs to find which one they are touching.

checkIntersection() just gives true or false depending on whether the finger position is lying in the rectangle of the Gridview child object.
[Image showing how the checkIntersection function works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2cts.png)

Update:
This is the whole block of code

```
//find the gridview view and assing it to a variable
        final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_boxes);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        //when user lifts finger off the screen, reset all boxes
        gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int action = event.getActionMasked();

                switch (action) {
                    //when finger is lifted off the gridView object
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //TODO after user lifts finger check if the path they chose has no obstacles
                        for (int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++)
                        {
                            ImageView gridChild = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
                            gridChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_square);
                        }
                        Log.d("SMEMS", "UP " + String.valueOf(action));
                        break;
                    //when finger touches the gridView
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //loop through all childs
                        for(int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++)
                        {
                            //check if finger position is above any child
                            ImageView gridChild = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
                            if(checkIntersection((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY(), gridChild.getLeft(), gridChild.getRight(), gridChild.getTop(), gridChild.getBottom())) {
                                gridChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_square);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("SMEMS", "DOWN. Y value: " + String.valueOf(event.getY()) + ", X value: " + String.valueOf(event.getX()));
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //TODO check if there is a more efficient way of doing this without a loop
                        //loop through all childs
                        for(int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++)
                        {
                            //check if finger position is above any child
                            ImageView gridChild = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
                            if(checkIntersection((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY(), gridChild.getLeft(), gridChild.getRight(), gridChild.getTop(), gridChild.getBottom())) {
                                gridChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_square);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the onTouchListener for the items being touched?

Comment: I want to detect a touch on an item even if the user does not lift his finger up and just slides it to the next item

Comment: That is what an OnTouchListener is for as opposed to the OnClickListener.  See below.

Comment: So what is your actual problem here?  You want to drag an entire gridview item? Or drag the child of a gridview item?

Comment: Kind of. I want to 'drag' a gridview child (in my case an imageview) to take it to the opposite corner. I won't actually drag it but change it's imageview resource depending on the position of the finger.

Comment: So you should implement an onTouchListeners on all the children item you care about and don't let the gridview intercept the clicks.

Comment: Will this help me avoid the For loop?

Comment: Oh.  Nevermind.  I see the problem now.  You are trying to detect if when the move action is over, there is an object below your finger.  Your method may be the only way to go.  The only other thought I would have is maybe setting on touch listeners on the children and keep a member variable of the last view touched.  That way you already know what view you are above.

Comment: I am trying to detect the object below my finger whenever my finger moves and I don't want to use a for loop.